# Does any Python library support writing arrays of structs to Parquet files?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I want to write data where some columns are arrays of strings or arrays of structs (typically key-value pairs) into a Parquet file for use in AWS Athena.

After finding two Python libraries (Arrow and fastparquet) supporting writing to Parquet files I have struggled for a while trying to achieve arrays of structs.

The top answer to a question of writing Parquet files list these two libraries (and do mention lacking support for nested data).

So is there a way to write nested data to Parquet files from Python?

---

I tried the following with *Arrow* in order to store key/values.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

countries = []
populations = []

countries.append('Sweden')
populations.append([{'city': 'Stockholm', 'population': 1515017}, {'city': 'Gothenburg', 'population': 590580}])
countries.append('Norway')
populations.append([{'city': 'Oslo', 'population': 958378}, {'city': 'Bergen', 'population': 254235}])


ty = pa.struct([pa.field('city', pa.string()),
                pa.field('population', pa.int32())
])

fields = [
    pa.field('country', pa.string()),
    pa.field('populations', pa.list_(ty)),
]
sch1 = pa.schema(fields)

data = [
    pa.array(countries),
    pa.array(populations, type=pa.list_(ty))
]
batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, ['country', 'populations'])
table = pa.Table.from_batches([batch], sch1)
writer = pq.ParquetWriter('cities.parquet', sch1)
writer.write_table(table)
writer.close()
```

When I ran the code I got the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    writer.write_table(table)
  File "/Users/moonhouse/anaconda2/envs/parquet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py", line 327, in write_table
    self.writer.write_table(table, row_group_size=row_group_size)
  File "_parquet.pyx", line 955, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetWriter.write_table
  File "error.pxi", line 77, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Nested column branch had multiple children
```

An [answer in a recent Arrow JIRA ticket](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2587) featuring the same error message suggests there is ongoing work of supporting structs although it is unclear to me if it covers writing or just reading of those.

---

When I tried to store data using *fastparquet* (like here when I had a list of strings):

```
import pandas as pd
from fastparquet import write

data = [{  'cities': ['Stockholm', 'Copenhagen', 'Oslo', 'Helsinki']}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
write('test.parq', df, compression='SNAPPY')
```

no error message was given but when viewed in parquet-tools I noticed that the data is Base64-encoded JSON.

```
cities = WyJTdG9ja2hvbG0iLCAiQ29wZW5oYWdlbiIsICJPc2xvIiwgIkhlbHNpbmtpIl0=
```

This is expected, I guess, given that [fastparquet doesn't support nested object arrays](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/272).

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out eventually?

Comment: No, I haven't checked the current status for support of this.

Comment: As of PyArrow 8.0.0, the `pa.field(...)` is no longer necessary. You can just pass a tuple of `(name, type)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Pulling arrow >= 0.17.0 should fix your error.

## Reference

PR: https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/6751

Comment: did this fix it, @moonhouse ?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Yes, can confirm that it works with a recent version of pyarrow. (tested with 10.0.0) and my example code now produces the result I expected.